# CRM error while trying to deserialize parameter

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have a CRM function that returns the attribute types of all attributes in a entity.  My problem is all though this same method has worked in the past it's now throwing this error regardless of the entity I pass in to it.

There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:ExecuteResult

Here is my code, I'm passing in the "account" entity.

```
public string GetFieldType(IOrganizationService svc, string entity, string fieldName)
        {
            RetrieveEntityRequest request = new RetrieveEntityRequest()
            {
                EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
                LogicalName = entity
            };

            RetrieveEntityResponse response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)svc.Execute(request);
            string type = "";
            foreach (AttributeMetadata attribute in response.EntityMetadata.Attributes)
            {
                if (attribute.LogicalName == fieldName)
                { type = attribute.AttributeType.ToString(); }
            }

            return type;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using early bound entities?

Answer (score 0):

If the code was working before, and it's not now, odds are that it is not a problem with your code.  Most likely your `svc.Execute` is failing.  Have you changed how your `IOrganizationService` is being created?  Are you running as a user with rights to query the CRM instance?  If all of these things check out, then try turning on server side tracing through the [diagnostic tool](http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/).